# Python build - trusted host

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a python wheel.
Pip is configured to use a custom repository, which is not (globally) trusted. When running

```
python -m build
```

I am hence being confronted with the following warning:

```
Uninstalling setuptools-41.2.0:
Successfully uninstalled setuptools-41.2.0
Looking in indexes: http://myRepository
WARNING: The repository located at myRepository is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS we recommend you use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyway with '--trusted-host artifactory'.
```

And the build will subsequently fail. However, trusted-host doesn't actually seem to be an accepted parameter:

```
python -m build --trusted-host myRepository
```

results in

```
usage: python -m build [-h] [--version] [--sdist] [--wheel] [--outdir OUTDIR] [--skip-dependency-check] [--no-isolation] [--config-setting CONFIG_SETTING] [srcdir]
python -m build: error: unrecognized arguments: --trusted-host
```

How can I run build while manually enabling myRepository to be trusted?

I am specifically looking for a solution that works on a per-command basis. Specifically, I cannot modify any global/user/site pip config files, move the repository over to https, or anything the like.

Comment: Can you just host your repository over HTTPS instead of insecure HTTP? That's better and probably easier than overriding its trust otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed you are not able to edit global config files. Maybe it will be useful for you to look towards venv config files.

I had experienced the same problem and next steps helped me:

1. I created file "C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini". I'm using Win 10. So if your OS is different, you need to specify where "pip.ini" should be located.
2. I located next lines inside "pip.ini":

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.
```

You may list there all repositories you need.

3. Try to run building again.